# How to organize a subfolder of modules which are also called as scripts?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script `hello.py` which can be used as a module by `main.py`, or be called from the command line. It itself imports a module `helper.py` which is in the same directory:

```
├── lib
│   ├── hello.py
│   ├── helper.py
│   ├── __init__.py
├── main.py
```

The contents of the files are

```
$ cat main.py
import lib.hello

lib.hello.sayhi()

------------------------------------

$ cat lib/hello.py
import helper

def sayhi():
    print("bonjour")
    print(helper.something())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("hello")

------------------------------------

$ cat lib/helper.py
def something():
    print("something")
```

The problem I have is that hello called from the command line works fine (imports `helper.py` correctly as it is at the same leval as `hello.py`) but when running main.py I get

```
$ python3 main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import lib.hello
  File "/tmp/lib/hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    import helper
ImportError: No module named 'helper'
```

because from the perspective of `main.py`, `helper.py` is in `lib`.

If I change the import in `hello.py` to `import lib.helper` then I have the same problem the other way round:

```
$ python3 hello.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    import lib.helper
ImportError: No module named 'lib'
```

**How do I get out of this catch 22 situation?**

I suspect that the information from "[PEP 338 -- Executing modules as scripts](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/)" could be useful but I fail to understand how to bring them in practice to my problem.

Comment: Seems to work for me in Python 2.

Comment: Does my [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39528736/how-do-you-organise-a-python-project-that-contains-multiple-packages-so-that-eac) help?

Answer (score 0):

you should set in hello.py

```
import lib.helper
```

and in the call of do something method:

```
lib.helper.something()
```

That solves your problem, you can call main or hello without problems