# Cannot import module in same directory and package

Tags: python, package, python-import

I'm using a `from . import module` statement to do exactly that: import a local module to my script. The script and module reside in the same folder.

```
# module.py
def foo():
    print('Foo!')

# script.py
from . import module
module.foo()

> ImportError: cannot import name 'module'
```

This should be pretty easy, and doing just `import module` does work, but as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39746026/7089239) suggests one should, I modified the statements to the former form.

**The end goal** is to have a package, from which I can use things, but also to have executable scripts inside the package that import other parts of that package. Apparently, after a few days worth of searching and a few questions I still don't quite understand the import and packaging machinery.

These might be the cause:

- Import statements are different in 2.7 and 3.x, I'm using 3.6, the question was on 2.7
- Relative imports are different inside packages (folder with `__init__.py`)
- The working directory is different or the folders are not in `sys.path`

Having an `__init__` file does not make a difference at least in a fresh project in PyCharm. Also, the working directory is set to the folder of the sources and it is in `path`.

Have I missed something? Or rather, **what's the correct way of achieving the functionality described in the end goal?** Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think you can do relative imports unless you are in a module. Your script is not a module. You may be able to do something like call it as a module `python -m script` but when you get to tha tstage you are probably not doing things correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since writing this answer I have realised it is more convenient and better style in my humble opinion to install the package with `pip install -e .` and use absolute imports. So even within a package writing `from package.sub.module import thing`. This makes refactoring a lot easier and there's no need to ever manipulate module variables or `sys.path`.

---

When running a script directly, Python consideres the name (a special variable, `__name__`) of that script to be `"__main__"`. In case of an import, the name is set to the name of the module. In the latter case relative imports are fine. But `import` actually looks at the combination of `__name__` and another special variable, `__package__`, which is `None` for an executed script, but the path to a module for an imported module, e.g. `parent.sub`.

The searched variable is... *drumroll*...

```
__package__ + '.' + __name__
```

The secret ingredient is manipulating `__package__`:

```
# script.py
__package__ = 'package_name'   # or parent.sub.package
from . import module
```

This lets Python know you *are* inside a package even though the script is executed directly. However, the top level folder needs to be in `sys.path` and the package name has to reflect that directory structure.

See [this very comprehensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/7089239) on the topic of relative imports.